# Blazor event isn't triggering. There must be an issue with my environment

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I was having issues with .NET 8 Blazor Web App events and getting them to trigger. It started when my @bind-Value on my textarea wasn't populating my booking.Text property. But I did some experimenting and it turns out that none of my delegate event handlers are working.

I isolated the issue to a new project with just that in it - No change
I restarted my PC - No change
I reinstalled visual studio 2022 - No change
I checked my setup, --version and --list-sdks:
[image]

Here's the code I entered:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<button @onclick="OnButtonClickWithArgs">Click Me</button>

@code {
    private void OnButtonClickWithArgs(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Button was clicked with mouse button: {args.Button}");
        // Additional logic here
    }
}
```

I couldn't hit the breakpoint and the console didn't contain the string from the console.writeline()

[image]

I'm convinced there is something wrong with my setup somehow. I just don't know what. I just need ideas of things to try really. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the code in code tags? Not as a printscreen.

Comment: Sorry @Taco I've fixed that now. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! It won't change my answer below, but it makes it easier for people to help you in future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the result of the render mode. [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

If you migrate from an old version to .net read [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio)

The primary suspect is the following in App.razor: `<Routes />` `<HeadOutlet />`. Those should both have the parameter rendermode: `<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveWebAssembly" />`

This is configured in the project creation wizard:

If you select Global it is configured for your entire project. With Per page/component (default) you have to configure it for every page/component. Global used to be the default/only-option in .net7 and before.

[image: wizard]

Comment: Just want to point out that the Microsoft doc link you posted has an invalid URL. It has the HTTPS:// twice.

Comment: This is my solution. I'm gonna do more research on these render modes. They totally new to me. But InteractiveWebAssembly rendermode caused an error. But using InteractiveServer worked perfectly. My delagate event handlers trigger perfectly now. Will mark this as the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Fixed the dupicate https://
And yes, render modes are introduced in .net8 and broke a lot of projects.

Answer (score 1):

After running the code provided, i found that the console message was being printed to the web browsers console. (F12 then go to console). and it was hitting the break points also.

checking the rendermode in routes to be `<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveAuto">`
and also checking to see if you have
`<ItemGroup> <ProjectReference Include="..\StackOverflowQuestionButton.Client\StackOverflowQuestionButton.Client.csproj" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="8.0.1" /> </ItemGroup>`
included in your
`<Project></Project>`

in TestProject