# Blazor .net8 @onclick don't work. How to fix it?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

I created a component in Blazor .net8, but @onclick is not active. it is not even the same color as in previous versions

[image]

it used to be like this
[image]

I do everything as in the old versions, only here I added rentermodes.

How to fix it?

Comment: The problem may be that I have imports in the default Components folder, and components in the shared/components folder.

Comment: Please post code as text and not as an image

Comment: Is probably the result of rendermode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78126746/blazor-event-isnt-triggering-there-must-be-an-issue-with-my-environment/78126921#78126921

Comment: @DarkBee, I've provided a picture of the code to show the color difference. 
You voted against it in vain. I did the right thing

Comment: @Taco, thank you, but I've already found the problem and the solution. It's an architecture change in the new version. I added the answer, but I will be able to mark it as correct only tomorrow

Comment: No, you did not - [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @DarkBee, You're wrong. I'm sticking to "Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.". Don't be a bore, please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After all the attempts and deliberations, I decided to duplicate the import file into the components folder. The solution is to move the import file to the level of `Program.cs`, as it was in previous versions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your in Visual Studio, it's a VS issue in linking the appropriate *_Imports.razor*  to the newly created component.

You don't need to add the specific `@using`.  The project will compile OK.

My fix is to save and close the component, and then reopen it.  MS seem incapable of solving the VS issues with adding and renaming Razor files.

Comment: Issue is not only in the assembly of the project... Unfortunately, the functionality of events does not work, as it was in previous versions

Answer (score -1):

I found a partial solution. For some reason, the component does not see this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web from global imports. If you add it to the markup file, everything will work.

`@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web`

Maybe someone knows how to fix global imports?